# Adding a string to an empty list in Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am trying to add a string to an empty list in Zapier code.

I have tried the code locally and it works. I don't understand why it's not working inside Zapier. Here is the code

```
output = []
if (input_data[0]=="true"): output.append("string")
```

Here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/tmpEeICti/usercode.py", line 10, in the_function
if (input_data[0]=="true"): output.append("Situationsplan")
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

`input_data` is a `dict` but you're accessing it like an array. There's not a `'0'` key, so you're getting that error. The keys in `input_data` are created right above the code input, so feel free to edit that form to get different data.

Additionally, `output` will need to be an array of `dict`s, so a value of `["Situationsplan"]` will cause an error once this actually does run.